# Frappe navigation arrows inside a form

Tags: javascript, python, html, erpnext, frappe

[Whenever I want to apply a filter on the list and then enter a form the arrows won't navigate based on the filter sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITPVp.png)

How can I customize the arrows to make them navigate based on the applied filter sorting ?

I have applied the date filter so the list was sorted by date after that when I entered the first form and clicked on the next arrow it gave the the form based on the default sorting (not the date sorting)
can I customize it using JavaScript code? using form script?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.